# How to synchronize computers in the cluster?

Tags: linux, mpi, cluster-computing

I have a Beowulf cluster with 10+ computers. Only the Master (2 NIC cards) is connected to LAN (Guarded cluster) while all other computers are connected to a switch. So when I do updates in the master how will I be able to synchronize  other computers in the cluster?

The OS is Ubuntu, and the cluster uses NFS and SSH.

Comment: [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/)?

Comment: Thank you Cong Ma.

Comment: Only the Master is connected to internet the hosts have no internet connection.

Comment: So setup routing (or NAT in the likely case compute nodes don't have public IP's) on the master so the compute nodes can access the net?

Comment: You could set the Master as the default gateway in all nodes. By switching IP forwarding on and off at the Master you would effectively connect and disconnect the nodes to/from the internet. Your router has to know about the subnet though. How do you configure the IP adresses at the nodes?

Comment: Master has public and private IP while all the hosts have only private IP and  I am not allowed do IP forwarding. Is there a way that i can install updates on Master and tell the hosts to get the updates from the master. All the computers have shared folders.

Comment: I tried copying all the debian files from /var/cache/apt/archives  to a shared folder and then doing sudo dpkg -i *.deb. But it is not working. If anyone has a better idea please let me know.

Comment: It should be quite easy to configure apt on the nodes to pull their stuff from the master (config is in /etc/apt/sources.list). But you would have to run your master as a debian mirror server. There are tutorials for this, but I never dared to read them.

Comment: Thank you Georg. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below approach:
https://odzangba.wordpress.com/2006/10/13/how-to-build-local-apt-repositories/

Thank you